# Calling a route from a template

Tags: python, flask

Can I have a route that renders a template that I can use in another template?

I imagine something like

```
@app.route('/tags/')
def tags():
    return render_template('tags.html', tags=create_tags())
```

and then somehow invoke the route from a different template.

```
<h2>Tags</h2>
{{ render('/tags/') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes don't render templates, functions do.  All the route does is point a url to a function.  So, the obvious solution to me is to have a function that returns the rendered tag template:

```
def render_tags_template():
    return render_template('tags.html', tags=create_tags())
```

Then we want to associate the function with the url "/tags"

```
app.add_url_rule('/tags', endpoint='tags', view_func=render_tags_template)
```

We also want to be able to access this function from within our templates.  Accessing it via the url through another request would most likely be a job for ajax.  So we have to get render_tags_template into the template context.

```
render_template('some_random_template.html', render_tags_template=render_tags_template
```

then in your some_random_template.html:

```
{{render_tags_template()}}
```

if you don't want to pass render_tags_template explicitly, you can add it as a template global:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['render_tags_template'] = render_tags_template
```

and use it freely in all of your templates, without having to pass it explicitly.

Depending on what your *actually* trying to do, simply including tags.html may be the best and easiest solution.  Using a function to generate the content gives you a bit more control and flexibility.

Comment: Also, you don't have to add the url rule if all you want to do is access this function from within a template.  If you want the user to go to /tags and view tags.html rendered solo, or provide an ajax api to fetch the template with javascript, then you can add the url_rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `tags.html` template in your template.

```
{% include "tags.html" %}
```

You have to pass the `tags` to your template, but this is the way to do it.